# Saved search for user search filter

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to create a saved search for a user using Toolset. step followed:

Created a form for save search
created post type
created a custom field to store search URL in post type
used Javascript code to pull the search URL.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var currentURL = window.location.href;
  $('[name="wpcf-search-url"]').val(currentURL);
});
```

The issue is the website has a custom setting for the permalink as %postname%  when I do the search as it has a custom setting for the permalink as [www.xxxx.org/](http://www.xxxx.org/) %postname%. how to get the search permalink for save search filter.

please guide me how i can resolve this